# Why my music won't play on Android Studio?

Tags: android

I'm using Android Studio.I tried all the codes that I've seen on the internet but my app doesn't work. I have a raw folder which contains the music that I'll be use but still I don't know what is the error in my code.

Here's my code:

```
 package com.example.aloja.babysteps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;



/**
 * Created by Aloja on 3/27/2017.
 */

public class A extends Activity {
    Button btnBack3,btnPlay;

    ImageView ivApple;
    MediaPlayer apple;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a);
        btnBack3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack3);
        btnPlay =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        ivApple = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivApple);
        ivApple.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);

        apple= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.apple);



        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                apple.start();

            }
        });
    }

        protected void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            apple.stop();
            apple.release();

    }

}
```

P.S Sorry for my english. Hope you understand what I'm trying to ask

Comment: Please post the error logs.
 what error you are getting?

Comment: I don't see any error here because my app is running but my music won't play.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code hope it will help you.

```
int resID=getResources().getIdentifier("filename", "raw", getPackageName());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);

mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

                        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "what=="+what);
                        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "extra=="+extra);

                        return false;
                    }
                });
mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

                        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "what=="+what);
                        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "extra=="+extra);
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: still won't play :9

Comment: check my edited answer and let me know what your log shows.

Answer (score 0):

I test your code on MX5 and it works well.

Did you enable your phone's music volume ?

(In MX5, you can see tone, media, notification and system volume.)